# Guy in the body of a girl or girl in the body of a guy?

Tags: fantasy, gender

I'm talking about teenagers/young adults.
If you had to choose one, which plot can be more fun (without being vulgar - maybe just a little bit) to write and to read?
Can you explain why and make some examples?

Keep in mind that it wouldn't be the main storyline, but part of the plot of one of the protagonists.

Comment: This is a "what to write"/discussion question, which is off-topic here.

Answer (score 3):

To be honest, it's pretty much the same.

It's the same scenario, same context, and generates roughly the same conflict.

But well, generally speaking, people tend to find the "boy in the body of a girl" funnier, maybe because of how we are conditioned to expect masculinity and toughness from men. Also because of how little we understand about the intricacies of the female mind, maybe.

But all in all, not that big of a deal really, pick what you like